# How to count by filter in SQL query?

Tags: sql

This is a part of my SQL query:

```
COUNT(t1.id) AS all_statuses_count,
COUNT(t1.status = 'completed') AS completed_statuses_count
```

What I want to get is count objects with ALL statuses, and count objects with specific status, 'completed' status in this case. How can I do that ?

Comment: please specify rdbms

Comment: What's the rest of your query? What does your data look like and what's an example of the output you want?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: In standard SQL you can do `count(*) filter (where t1.status = 'completed')`

Comment: SELECT
t3.id AS this_id,
t3.title AS this_title,
COUNT(t1.id) AS all_statuses_count,
COUNT(t1.status='completed') AS completed_statuses_count

FROM orders_order AS t1
JOIN orders_orderinfo AS t2
ON t1.id=t2.order_id
JOIN restaurants_restaurant AS t3
ON t2.restaurant_id=t3.id

WHERE t3.is_deleted=False
GROUP BY this_id

Comment: @Madi7 Don't hide important information in the comments. Edit your question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.id) AS all_records,
       SUM(CASE WHEN t1.status = 'completed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS completed_status_count
FROM t1
```

Something like this should work. A bit confused about your first count though. Maybe you're looking for something a bit more window-function based. I honestly can't tell.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly, in my first count I wanted to get all statuses (I have 7 of them in total) and in second count I wanted to get only: status='completed'. However is your query rational in terms of performance ?

Comment: @Madi7 Yes, this should work just fine for you. If you have duplicate `t1.id` in that status table you might want to consider a `COUNT(DISTINCT t1.id)`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(t1.id) AS all_statuses_count, (SELECT COUNT(t1.status) FROM 
tb_Name WHERE t1.status='completed') AS completed_statuses_count
FROM tb_Name ;
```