# SQL How to show & group by two same columns of which one is more filtered?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery

There's a need to show few columns like years, weeks, severity, alarms and same alarms as previous, just more filtered. How to add the last column, which is the same as previous, just more filtered?

Example:

```
SELECT 
CAST(DATEPART( yy, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ) AS VARCHAR) AS YEAR,
CAST(DATEPART( wk, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ) AS VARCHAR) AS MONTH,
rSEV.NAME AS SEVERITY,
COUNT(rSTA.ALARMIDKEY) AS ALARMS
FROM 
    REPORTER.reporter.REPORTER_STATUS rSTA
INNER JOIN
    REPORTER.reporter.REP_SEVERITY_TYPES rSEV
    ON
    rSTA.ORIGINALSEVERITY = rSEV.SEVERITY
WHERE
    rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY > DATEADD(week, -10, GETDATE())
    AND
    rSEV.NAME != 'Clear'
GROUP BY
    DATEPART( yy, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ),
    DATEPART( wk, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ),
    rSEV.NAME
ORDER BY
    DATEPART( yy, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ) DESC,
    DATEPART( wk, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ) DESC
```

This query produces first 4 columns correctly, attaching picture:[ALARMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfEX3.jpg)

The fifth column should be the same as ALARMS, but with condition:

```
SELECT ALARMIDKEY AS ALARMS_CC FROM REPORTER.reporter.REPORTER_STATUS WHERE
                    (MAINTMODECRONTAB != 'Y'
                     AND SUPPRESSESCL < 4
                     AND SPMAUTO != 1
                     AND ORIGINALSEVERITY > 0)
                     AND ((AIWAVER = 3 AND EVENTACTOR = 1)
                          OR
                          ((AIWAVER < 3 OR AIWAVER IS NULL)
                           AND ((CONTROLCENTREVIEW = 1
                                 AND ORIGINALSEVERITY = 5)
                                OR (CONTROLCENTREVIEW = 2)
                                OR (ALERTGROUP = 'CHECKLIST')
                               )
                          )
                         )
```

Now I wonder how to add this condition into to the main (first) query and group it by, so that it would produce correct data. For every year,week and severity show alarms and alarmsCC(same column, just different conditions).
I hope that it would look like this:[ALARMS_CC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTuaH.jpg)

Hope it makes it clear what I want to achieve. Would be great if the way to do achieve this would be more optimized. Maybe JOIN is possible?

Comment: Are You sure You need answers for two, different databases?

Comment: This is the same database, Year,week and alarms are located in same table. Severity is taken from another table.

Comment: You have tagged the question both Microsoft SQL Server and MySQL. These are two different relational database management systems. Do You need one answer for both?

Comment: Sorry, messed up tags somehow. Fixed now. MSSQL server is being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the additonal filtered alarms by selecting them via a subquery, like this:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(DATEPART( yy, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ) AS VARCHAR) AS YEAR,
    CAST(DATEPART( wk, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ) AS VARCHAR) AS MONTH,
    rSEV.NAME AS SEVERITY,
    COUNT(rSTA.ALARMIDKEY) AS ALARMS,
    filtered.ALARMS_CC
FROM REPORTER.reporter.REPORTER_STATUS rSTA
INNER JOIN REPORTER.reporter.REP_SEVERITY_TYPES rSEV
           ON rSTA.ORIGINALSEVERITY = rSEV.SEVERITY
INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(ALARMIDKEY) AS ALARMS_CC, 
                   DATEPART( yy, FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ) AS year, 
                   DATEPART( wk, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ) AS month,
                   ORIGINALSEVERITY AS os
            FROM REPORTER.reporter.REPORTER_STATUS 
            WHERE
                (MAINTMODECRONTAB != 'Y'
                 AND SUPPRESSESCL < 4
                 AND SPMAUTO != 1
                 AND ORIGINALSEVERITY > 0)
                 AND ((AIWAVER = 3 AND EVENTACTOR = 1)
                      OR
                      ((AIWAVER < 3 OR AIWAVER IS NULL)
                       AND ((CONTROLCENTREVIEW = 1
                             AND ORIGINALSEVERITY = 5)
                            OR (CONTROLCENTREVIEW = 2)
                            OR (ALERTGROUP = 'CHECKLIST')
                           )
                      )
                     )
            GROUP BY DATEPART( yy, FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ), 
                     DATEPART( wk, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ),
                     ORIGINALSEVERITY 
          ) AS filtered ON DATEPART( yy, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ) = filtered.year AND
                           DATEPART( wk, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ) = filtered.month AND
                           rSTA.ORIGINALSEVERITY = filtered.os
WHERE
    rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY > DATEADD(week, -10, GETDATE())
    AND
    rSEV.NAME != 'Clear'
GROUP BY
    DATEPART( yy, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ),
    DATEPART( wk, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ),
    rSEV.NAME
ORDER BY
    DATEPART( yy, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ) DESC,
    DATEPART( wk, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ) DESC
```

Comment: It does actually seem to work ! And if I add 54 weeks instead of 10 it doesn't affect time to complete the query. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can try using case statement referring in this post - [How to count by filter in SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47175936/how-to-count-by-filter-in-sql-query).

So the query will look like

```
    SELECT 
        CAST(DATEPART( yy, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ) AS VARCHAR) AS YEAR,
        CAST(DATEPART( wk, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ) AS VARCHAR) AS MONTH,
        rSEV.NAME AS SEVERITY,
        COUNT(rSTA.ALARMIDKEY) AS ALARMS,

        SUM(CASE WHEN rSTA.MAINTMODECRONTAB != 'Y'
                             AND rSTA.SUPPRESSESCL < 4
                             AND rSTA.SPMAUTO != 1
                             AND rSTA.ORIGINALSEVERITY > 0)
                             AND ((rSTA.AIWAVER = 3 AND rSTA.EVENTACTOR = 1)
                                  OR
                                  ((rSTA.AIWAVER < 3 OR rSTA.AIWAVER IS NULL)
                                   AND ((rSTA.CONTROLCENTREVIEW = 1
                                         AND rSTA.ORIGINALSEVERITY = 5)
                                        OR (rSTA.CONTROLCENTREVIEW = 2)
                                        OR (rSTA.ALERTGROUP = 'CHECKLIST')
                                       )
                                  ))
                    THEN 1
                    ELSE 0 END) AS ALARMS_CC
    FROM 
        REPORTER.reporter.REPORTER_STATUS rSTA
    INNER JOIN
        REPORTER.reporter.REP_SEVERITY_TYPES rSEV
        ON
        rSTA.ORIGINALSEVERITY = rSEV.SEVERITY
    WHERE
        rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY > DATEADD(week, -10, GETDATE())
        AND
        rSEV.NAME != 'Clear'
    GROUP BY
        DATEPART( yy, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ),
        DATEPART( wk, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ),
        rSEV.NAME
    ORDER BY
        DATEPART( yy, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ) DESC,
        DATEPART( wk, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ) DESC
```

**UPDATE**

I am adding a more optimized query below.

```
    WITH REPORTER_STATUS_FILTERED AS
    (
        SELECT ALARMIDKEY
        FROM REPORTER.reporter.REPORTER_STATUS
        WHERE MAINTMODECRONTAB != 'Y'
            AND SUPPRESSESCL < 4
            AND SPMAUTO != 1
            AND ORIGINALSEVERITY > 0)
            AND ((AIWAVER = 3 AND EVENTACTOR = 1)
                OR
                ((AIWAVER < 3 OR AIWAVER IS NULL)
                AND ((CONTROLCENTREVIEW = 1
                        AND ORIGINALSEVERITY = 5)
                    OR (CONTROLCENTREVIEW = 2)
                    OR (ALERTGROUP = 'CHECKLIST')
                    )
                ))
    )

    SELECT 
        CAST(DATEPART( yy, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ) AS VARCHAR) AS YEAR,
        CAST(DATEPART( wk, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ) AS VARCHAR) AS MONTH,
        rSEV.NAME AS SEVERITY,
        COUNT(rSTA.ALARMIDKEY) AS ALARMS,
        COUNT(rSTA1.ALARMIDKEY) AS ALARMS_CC
    FROM 
        REPORTER.reporter.REPORTER_STATUS rSTA
    INNER JOIN
        REPORTER.reporter.REP_SEVERITY_TYPES rSEV
        ON
        rSTA.ORIGINALSEVERITY = rSEV.SEVERITY
    LEFT JOIN
        REPORTER_STATUS_FILTERED rSTA1
        ON
        rSTA.ALARMIDKEY = rSTA1.ALARMIDKEY
    WHERE
        rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY > DATEADD(week, -10, GETDATE())
        AND
        rSEV.NAME != 'Clear'
    GROUP BY
        DATEPART( yy, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ),
        DATEPART( wk, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ),
        rSEV.NAME
    ORDER BY
        DATEPART( yy, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ) DESC,
        DATEPART( wk, rSTA.FIRSTOCCURRENCEDAY ) DESC
```

Comment: Yes it seems to work with 10 weeks, if I set 54 weeks instead it takes quite much time. Wonder if it can be optimized or that's just the way it is?

Comment: I have updated the answer with a more optimized one. Can you please try that?

Answer (score 0):

```
select YEAR, MONTH, SEVERITY, ALARMS, ALARMS_CC 
from (Q1) as T1 left join (Q2) as T2 on
T1.YEAR = T2.YEAR 
and T1.MONTH = T2.MONTH
and T1.SEVERITY = T1.SEVERITY
ORDER BY YEAR DESC, MON DESC
```

Where Q1 is your query without order by section
and Q2 is first query with additional conditions and last column_name changed.
It's important to put Q1, Q2 into brackets ().